# Stop Firefox from asking me about blocking Flash

Tags: macos, firefox, adobe-flash

Lately it seems like there's a new "critical" update to Flash every week or so. And every single time this happens Firefox begins prompting me to Allow or Disallow flash on every single website I visit which uses it. Until in frustration I give in and update Flash.

The thing is, I don't necessarily want to update flash. I also don't want to continually click "Allow" on a multitude of websites.

Is there a global configuration setting that either says "Allow Flash forever on all websites" or "Stop asking me I don't care, just leave me alone already Firefox"

Note: Flash is already set to "Always Activate" so that doesn't work.  This is something **new** that's just begun happening and it happens across all platforms I use firefox on - Linux, OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the automatically redownload of blocklist.xml in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration#about:config), as described below - source: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Blocklist.xml

> blocklist.xml is a file in the [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder).
>
> blocklist.xml contains a list of add-ons that Mozilla considers to be harmful to the user (contains security vulnerabilities, adversely affects browsing experience, etc.). Any installed add-on on the block list will be disabled and any attempt to install an add-on on the block list will result in an error. A list of the add-ons currently on the block list can be found on the Mozilla [Add-ons Blocklist](https://www.mozilla.com/blocklist/) page.
>
> blocklist.xml is by default automatically downloaded once a day from mozilla.com. The blocklist functionality can be disabled by [extensions.blocklist.enabled](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Extensions.blocklist.enabled), be modified to point to a different URL by [extensions.blocklist.url](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Extensions.blocklist.url), and changed in frequency by [extensions.blocklist.interval](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Extensions.blocklist.interval).
>
> **Editing**
>
> blocklist.xml is by default automatically redownloaded once a day. As such, any changes made will be overwritten. If you wish to edit this file manually, it's recommended you turn off the update functionality by changing [extensions.blocklist.url](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Extensions.blocklist.url) to be null.
>
> The syntax of the file is described [here](http://wiki.mozilla.org/Extension_Blocklisting:Code_Design).
>
> **Moving**
>
> This file can be moved to a different profile without any extra effort, but since it's automatically overwritten once a day, there's no point.
>
> **Deleting**
>
> Deleting blocklist.xml will clear the block list until the file is redownloaded.

Comment: I think you might just be cooler than school.

Comment: Won't this stop asking about ALL plugins, though? What if one wants to avoid this for Flash only, but the other problematic plugins SHOULD be checked?

Isn't this killing a fly with a grenade?

Answer (score -3):

Had problems with Flash as well. Also Firefox would not allow setting "Always activate". After trying to load the latest version (unsuccessfully) many times I uninstalled it from my system (Windows XP) and downloaded the latest version - not through Adobe - but at http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html
Load the latest 18.0.0.205 Beta version. No problems so far. Hope this helps.